# How can I run this PHP website and host it on HostGator?

Tags: php, html, web, hosting

My friend, who just started a company, sent me this website (https://github.com/lexaugustin/bamboufacile) that someone built for him out of a PHP template, so I can host it for him on "hostgator.com". When I run the public folder with XAMPP, I only see the template website, and when I try to run the server.php that is in the root directory, I get these two errors:

1) "Warning: require(/opt/lampp/htdocs/public/../vendor/autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /opt/lampp/htdocs/public/index.php on line 24

2) Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required '/opt/lampp/htdocs/public/../vendor/autoload.php' (include_path='.:/opt/lampp/lib/php') in /opt/lampp/htdocs/public/index.php on line 24.

Can someone help me run this file and tell me how to host PHP website on hostgator, please? The tutorials on hostgator haven't worked for me.

Comment: You're missing all the dependencies which are managed by composer. 1. https://getcomposer.org/ 2. Run `composer install` while inside the directory that contains `composer.json` and `composer.lock`.

Answer (score 0):

The project link you have mentioned is a laravel project. The error shows it has missing dependencies. So first thing you will need to install [composer](https://getcomposer.org/download/) to install its dependencies.

Once you are done with the installation open command line and cd to your project directory in xampp htdocs. Run this below command to install the dependencies. Also you will need minimum **php 7.1.3** in your xampp and hostgator to run this project.

> composer install